# How to get Subscription Revenue data through the YouTube API?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

Does the YouTube Reports API provide access to the **final Subscription Revenue** data?

I can only get the Ads Revenue data for now.

**Example**

First, I installed the library

```
composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
```

Then, I used the below code to get all supported jobs

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit'
];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setDeveloperKey('YOUR_API_KEY');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setScopes($scopes);
$client->refreshToken('YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN');
$client->setRedirectUri('');

$reportingService = new \Google_Service_YouTubeReporting($client);
$optParams = [
    'onBehalfOfContentOwner' => 'YOUR_CONTENT_OWNER_ID',
    'includeSystemManaged' => true,
];

$jobs = $reportingService->jobs->listJobs($optParams);
$jobNames = array_map(function($job) {
    return $job->getReportTypeId();
}, $jobs->getJobs());

print_r($jobNames);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => content_owner_playlist_traffic_source_a1
    [1] => content_owner_sharing_service_a1
    [2] => content_owner_claim_ad_revenue_summary_a1
    [3] => content_owner_asset_conflict_a1
    [4] => content_owner_ad_revenue_summary_a1
    [5] => content_owner_asset_demographics_a1
    [6] => content_owner_asset_sharing_service_a1
    [7] => content_owner_asset_annotations_a1
    [8] => content_owner_asset_ad_revenue_summary_a1
    [9] => content_owner_asset_cards_a1
    [10] => content_owner_cards_a1
    [11] => content_owner_playlist_device_os_a1
    [12] => content_owner_ad_revenue_raw_a1
    [13] => content_owner_playlist_combined_a1
    [14] => content_owner_annotations_a1
    [15] => content_owner_playlist_province_a1
    [16] => content_owner_playlist_playback_location_a1
    [17] => content_owner_video_metadata_a2
    [18] => content_owner_playlist_basic_a1
    [19] => content_owner_active_claims_a1
    [20] => content_owner_video_metadata_a1
    [21] => content_owner_demographics_a1
    [22] => content_owner_active_references_a1
    [23] => content_owner_asset_a1
    [24] => content_owner_asset_ad_revenue_raw_a1
)
```

There is no job about the **final Subscription Revenue**.

It's really appreciate if there is documents or examples about this.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: please post some code to your post.

Comment: Hi @sogu, I have added the example code about this issue. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: keep up on the good path.